# Created docker container is not running AND cannot be removed or killed

Tags: docker, bind, nvidia, mount

I want to

1. run ubuntu container,
   such that
2. it has a bind to an existing network storage located at "/mnt/datastore/Medical",
3. it has a mount to an existing docker volume named "mkdc_datasets",
4. it has a mount to an existing docker volume named "rsna_sct",
5. it can use local GPUs
   Also, I want it to be **interactive**.

So, here i have this command:

**Code updated**:

```
docker run -it\
  --name=sct_mkdc \
  --mount type=volume,source=mkdc_datasets,target=/dst \
  --mount type=volume,source=rsna_sct,target=/dst2 \
  --mount type=bind,source=/mnt/datastore/Medical,target=/src \
  --interactive --rm --gpus all ubuntu:latest
```

it creates a docker container that is not interactive, is not runing and cannot be removed or stoped without sudo command that I do not have permission to.

The ideas that I run nvidia-smi or that there was a -d option that does not work. Even runing simple

```
docker run --name=sct_mkdc --interactive --rm --gpus all ubuntu:latest
```

does the same thing. A container that is created and cannot be deleted.

What am I doing wrong here?

I expect that someone would point me what is the problem. I am ML-engineer, not a devops guy, so please keep it simple.

I tried to stop it by `docker stop sct_mkdc`, `docker rm -f sct_mkdc`, `docker rm -f 61ac9cb6e612`, `docker kill 61ac9cb6e612`. All of them do not seem to work.

Comment: The two obvious things that jump out at me are (1) you're launching the container `-d` in the background, and (2) you're trying to run a `nvidia-smi` command in an unmodified `ubuntu:latest` image that probably doesn't contain it.

Comment: changing it in the following manner ```docker run -it\
  --name=sct_mkdc \
  --mount type=volume,source=mkdc_datasets,target=/dst \
  --mount type=volume,source=rsna_sct,target=/dst2 \
  --mount type=bind,source=/mnt/datastore/Medical,target=/src \
  --interactive -rm --gpus all ubuntu:latest``` does not help.

Comment: The problem is in the part ```--gpus all```

Answer (score 0):

I see that you use `--rm` and don't use `-d`, when you don't use `-d` the container running in the current terminal (not in the background), and you are attached to it. If the command is failed, or you close this terminal, the container is stopped and removed automatically (`--rm` flag)

Could you show me the logs of that command?

Comment: docker logs --tail 1000 -f d7a0500b086b14d96803fe4f35a767dd716dd6ac5fe0affd38cad9813048d021

Comment: The problem is in the part ```--gpus all```